# Does Jenkins essentially function like a package manager for your software product?

Tags: continuous-integration, packages, continuous-delivery, automation, jenkins

I'm a relatively new IT Ops guy in a software (web) development company. Recently I deployed a virtual machine on OpenStack, because some developer needs it, and then I installed their application (written by our developers, not third party application) on that newly deployed server using Jenkins.

So basically, what I did was to install an application automatically on a server using Jenkins. This feels like installing a software on a Linux PC using a package manager like APT in Ubuntu, where everything is handled automatically by the package manager.

So, is the purpose of Jenkins to function like some automatic software installer? Is Jenkins essentially a package manager?

Comment: I would not consider Jenkins a package manager. Package managers are very specific tools. Jenkins is a million different things (mostly build and deploy). Jenkins is a package manager the same way that the back of a screwdriver is a hammer.

Comment: We use Jenkins for orchestration .. and have it run Ansible jobs to do automated software installation management, and use Chocolatey to actually install the packages. Of those only Chocolatey could really be described as a "package manager".

Comment: @Noob_Guy with this kind of language you are more likely to get even more downvotes.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Jenkins user guide and documentation which explains what Jenkins is, and how it's typically used:  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/  -- The front page summarises it fairly well: *"Jenkins is a self-contained, open source automation server which can be used to automate all sorts of tasks related to building, testing, and delivering or deploying software."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### What are the differences between a package manager and Jenkins ?

A package manager:

1. Is a local tool usually present on the same system *where software is intended to be installed*.
2. Does nothing other than what it is intended for: Queries, Installs, Upgrades and Uninstalls software.
3. Relies on a remote repository to query and fetch packages from.

On the other hand, Jenkins:

1. Is a server usually installed on a separate system.
2. Does a lot more that install software. Actually, its primary job is to perform CI-CD (Continuous Integration & Continuous Deployment).
3. Publishes built packages to remote repositories.

###### But, is a Package Manager the only way to install software ?

No. You could manually copy files to the target machine and do the changes yourself. Or, you could automate all of this in a script or a tool like Ansible.

###### So, can Jenkins install software without being a package manager ?

Absolutely. That's the "Deployment" part of CI-CD. Jenkins is perfectly able to "automate" the steps of a manual installation. It is even able to remotely "invoke" a package manager present on some other system.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is more of an orchestrator than a package manager, but a package manager is a fairly complex idea that made up of many parts. The power of Jenkins is being able to define a small step/process, then use that step as part of a larger process or as part of many different processes. You could use Jenkins to define the process of what happens when a user requests a package through a package manager, but you would need other tools to store packages and track dependencies.